Unhide rows in Excel with password
I use code to automatically hide/unhide rows in my worksheet.
I need additional code to ask for a password before unhiding rows.
Sub Macro1()

    Rows("125:192").Select

    If Rows("125:192").Hidden = True Then
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub


Your question has a lot of similarities with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700888/how-to-code-in-vba-for-requesting-password-when-clicked-on-a-button. Do you see an answer there that solves your problem?

Thank you, but I just wanted to add password to unhide the rows, not the worksheet.

But it's essentially the same concept: How to ask for a password from the user before performing a specific operation. Once you understand that concept, you can easily replace which operation you perform.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50850857/6600940

You might consider surrounding your "unhide" portion with an "IF" statement and then use an "InputBox" to ask your user to enter the unhide code. However a user could still manually unhide the rows if sheet protection isn't used.
Sub Macro1()

  Rows("125:192").Select

  If Rows("125:192").Hidden = True Then

  If "UNHIDE1!" = InputBox("Enter password to unhide", "Password", "") Then
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    MsgBox ("Rows unhidden")
    Else
    MsgBox ("Password incorrect")

    End If
  Else
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
  End If

End Sub

